# FreeRadius EAP-TLS Auth using Email Address

Tags: active-directory, certificate, freeradius

We have a requirement to authenticate devices to WIFI using the user's email address stored in AD. The devices are enrolled into InTune and the only shared piece of information is the email address.

How can I change FreeRadius to authenticate using the email address instead of the username?

Do I need to perform some form of LDAPSearch using the email address to get the username?

Will this work with EAP authentication using SSL certs? The SSL certs are created OnPrem and use the email address.

Any ideas?